# css dropdown navigation not right in IE 7 or 6

Tags: html, css, navigation, drop-down-menu

Trying to figure out what in the world is going on with IE7 and my CSS navigation dropdown.

It displays correctly in every other browser I have tried but in IE7, it drops down fine but as you hover over the links some of them will randomly appear/dissapear.  It is driving me crazy!

Here is my HTML for the menu:

```
<div id="navCatTabsWrapper">
<div id="navCatTabsDropdown">
<ul>
<li><a class="category-top" href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=39">All Products</a></li>
<li><a class="category-top" href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1">Dinnerware</a>
<ul>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=11"><li>Appetizer / Dessert / Salad</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=9"><li>Bowls</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=40"><li>Bread & Butter</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=12"><li>Buffet / Charger Plates</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=10"><li>Cups / Mugs</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=7"><li>Dinner Plates</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=6"><li>Dinnerware Sets</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class="category-top" href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=3">Drinkware</a>
<ul>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=27"><li>Acrylic</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=42"><li>Bar Accessories</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=41"><li>Pitchers</li></a>
 <a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=26"><li>Wine Glasses</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the drop down:

```
#navCatTabsWrapper 
{
margin: 0em;
/*background-color: #BD0044;*/ 
background-image:url(../images/nav-bg.jpg);
backgroud-repeat:repeat-x;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff; 
height:30px;
width: 100%;
}

#navCatTabs ul  
{
margin: 0;
padding:  0.5em 0em;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.5em;
}

#navCatTabs ul li 
{
display: inline;
}

#navCatTabs ul li a 
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0em 0.5em;
margin: 0;
color: #fff;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown 
{
margin-top: -20px;
height:30px;
font-size:120%;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown ul li 
{
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown * li ul
{
display: block;
left: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
padding: 0em;
margin-left:0.5em;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 100;

}

#navCatTabsDropdown * ul li
{
display: block;
text-align: left;
list-style-type: none;

}

#navCatTabsDropdown * li:hover ul 
{
visibility:visible;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 2px outset;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown * li:hover ul li
{
padding-left:0.5em;
padding-right:0.5em;
padding-top:0.25em;
padding-bottom:0.25em;
 }

#navCatTabsDropdown * li:hover ul li:hover
{
background-color:#BD0044;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown * ul li:hover
{
color:#fff;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown ul li a.category-top 
{
display:inline-block;
color:#fff;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
}

#navCatTabsDropdown ul li a.category-top:hover
{
background:url(../images/nav-bg-hover.jpg) repeat-x;
color:#BD0044;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your markup is all out of whack. You're nesting list items inside your anchor tags under your unordered list in your submenu and that is wrong, so we can start by fixing that.

```
<li>
    <a class="category-top" href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1">Dinnerware</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=11">Appetizer / Dessert / Salad</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=9">Bowls</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=40">Bread & Butter</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=12">Buffet / Charger Plates</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=10">Cups / Mugs</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=7">Dinner Plates</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=6">Dinnerware Sets</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

After that is done, you need to properly target your submenu items, currently you're using something like this:

```
#navCatTabsDropdown * li ul { ... }
```

Which i can't even comprehend how its working, so you can fix that by eliminating that asterisk sign.

And now on to your issue. Your submenu is not properly positioning itself under your menu item because it does not have a `top` reference from where to open from. You can fix that by adding `top:100%` to your submenu, this way it will open up exactly `100%` away from your menu item, this way the submenu will position itself exactly below your menu item automatically.

```
#navCatTabsDropdown li ul {
 top: 100%;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle with your code and all the fixes in place: http://jsfiddle.net/vaGDF/2/, though i would suggest you start from the top and rewrite your menu properly. Here is a simple menu i made for another answer such as this one that you can use as base: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/pc8wN/1/

Comment: I didn't really understand the asterisk either.  It's a template I am modifying.  Correcting this seems to fix it!  Thanks.